# Get RibbonTab scrollbar functionality

Tags: c#, .net, ribboncontrolslibrary

How can I get horizontal RibbonTab Scrollbar functionality in System.Windows.Control.Ribbon like shown here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, what did not work?

Comment: @zespri I tried every link in Google I could see, but couldn't see any implementation details. I can't see any Scroll or AllowResize properties on the Ribbon or the RibbonTabs themselves.